# Can I define more than one function under the where syntax?

Tags: haskell

I just see an example, which is checking if a list is nondescendant

```
nondec :: Ord a => [a] -> Bool
nondec xs = and (map leq (zip xs (tail xs)))
            where leq (x, y) = x <= y
```

I'm wondering can I define more than one function under the where syntax.

For example, if the map function is undefined, can I define it as this

```
where leq (x, y) = x <= y
      map(...)
```

Comment: Little tip: you can put them right below the `where` without additional indentation. This saves you horizontal (screen) space.

Comment: Off-topic, but instead of explicitly defining an uncurried version of `(<=)` and using `map`, you can use `zipWith`: `nondec xs = and (zipWith (<=) xs (tail xs))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can I define it as this

Why not try it? Because yes, you can do it exactly like this. `leq` and `map` just need to start in the same column and to the right of the column where the line with `where` starts (not necessarily to the right of `where` itself).

I think the Wikibook [explains the rules for indentation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation#The_golden_rule_of_indentation) quite well.

Answer (score 2):

Indent, as usual:

```
nondec :: Ord a => [a] -> String
nondec as = map leq as where
                          leq = id
                          map _ _ = "Hi!"
```

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that this is significantly more indented than necessary. I usually would just indent 2 spaces there (and some people like 4 spaces).

Comment: @DavidYoung Sure, it is merely to emphasize that both statements belong to the where block.

Comment: Unreleated: you put the java tag on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51022476/why-foreach-loop-iterates-more-than-the-no-of-items ... that is for sure NOT java. Please be a bit more careful with such edits! I think this would rather be C# ?!